# Validation rule: ISBLANK

Tags: validation, isblank

I need to display an error when a checkbox(field1) is true , AND if either of field2 or field3 is blank. The formula below doesn't work.

AND(field1=true,  ISBLANK(field2) II ISBLANK(field3))

Is there something I am missing?

Comment: what type of  field2 and  field3?. field 2 and field 3 should be text fields. check isblnak /isnull funcitons

Answer (score 3):

ISBLANK only works on some data types when "Treat blanks as zeroes" is selected. If you use "Treat blanks as zeroes", ISBLANK will not work for numeric data types.

As an aside, there's no need to use "= true" for checkboxes, because they are already True or False, so you can simply write your formula like this:

```
Field1 && (ISBLANK(Field2) || ISBLANK(Field3))
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you have 1 Boolean and 2 Text field. If so take a look at the following:

```
AND( 
field1 = TRUE, 
OR( 
ISBLANK(field2), 
ISBLANK(field3) 
) 
)
```

Above logic is designed based on the following assumptions.

> field1 = Boolean, 
>   field2 = Text, 
>   field3 = Text

In Salesforce validation rules we can use the syntax:

- AND
- &&
- OR
- ||

Syntax to use is a matter of preference.

Comment: We can use either AND/OR or &&/||, actually. It's all a matter of preference.

Comment: @sfdcfox That is correct, rephrasing above statement.

Comment: @sfdcfox At the risk of sounding overly anal, is there a 'best practice' here, to use either AND/OR or &&/II? I guess using the former is slightly better practice since it's more likely a non-developer would understand it.

Comment: @AndyHitchings They both have the same performance characteristics. I personally prefer && and ||, because of my developer background, but I find AND/OR to be equally easy to read. I think consistency is more important, preferring to use only &&/|| or AND/OR within a single formula, simply due to cognitive load.